# For each loop of Iterator skips first element

Tags: java, iterator

For school I had to made a kind of linked list like queue.
My nodes have 3 attributes:

- Node left (Node left of the node)
- Node right (Node right of the node)
- Object item (The object that is stored in the list)

I also have to make the list iterable so implemented that interface.

The problem I have now is that if there are for example 4 items in the list, it only shows 3 of them.

So if for example the list has 4 strings in it, 'a', 'b', 'c' and 'd' the output is:

```
b
c
d
```

My hasNext method looks like:

```
@Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return node.getRight() != null;
        }
```

and my next method looks like:

```
@Override
        public T next() {
            node = node.getRight();
            Object item = node.getItem();
            return (T)item;
        }
```

If I return the item of the node instead of the node on the right I get

```
a
b
c
```

as return but that is also not good because it skips the last one. And when you read the API next should return the next value so I guess my next method has to be as it is.

Comment: Return the item of the node and check if the node itself equals to null in the hasNext method. Also read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Good link very interesting, will definitely use the tips in the future. I did most of the steps already and found the problem but did not know how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iterator's methods should be implemented as this:

```
@Override
public T next() {
    Object item = node.getItem();
    node = node.getRight();
    return (T)item;
}

@Override
public boolean hasNext() {
    return node != null;
}
```

Just think about other iterators. At the first call of `next()` they return the first element and THEN they move forward to the second. When you are pointing to the last element, `next()` should return it and move forward (i.e. point to `null`). To be able to do this, the test inside of `hasNext` should be on the current item, not on the next, otherwise you could not get the last element.

Comment: Ofcourse! Thank you. I found out that I wasn't going to the last because of that problem but did not yet found out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably initialize the `node` property by setting it to the first node, so a next () call points to the second. Try checking for the first node:

```
boolean first = true;

@Override public T next() { 
if (!first) {
node = node.getRight(); 
}
else 
first = false;
Object item = node.getItem();
return (T)item;
}
```